# Format matplotlib figure ticks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib together with tkinter to display graphs. I am trying to change the format of my y-axis ticks to fit the need of the graph. Here is what I have tried.

```
a.set_title('Ending AUM')
a.set_xlabel('Dates')
a.set_ylabel('Ending AUM ($)')
a.grid(True)
a.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

However this formats the ticks to an integer with commas in the thousands marks. Shown here. [image]

How would I format this so the y-axis ticks began with a $ and ended with a decimal. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`StrMethodFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter) class, giving it a format string that uses the same [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) as Python's `str.format()` function.

The format string in this case, beginning with a dollar sign and ending with a decimal, would be `"${x:.2f}"`.  The `x` labels the field, the `StrMethodFormatter` class allows two fields in the format string: `x` for the value and `pos` for the position.

The last line in your code would become:

```
a.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("${x:.2f}"))
```

If you want more or less decimal places just change the number `2`.  If you wanted to keep the thousands separators add a comma after the colon: `"${x:,.2f}"`.